# How to access AAD B2C tenant with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, command-line-interface, azure-ad-b2c, azure-cli

I need to get user details in AAD B2C tenant I have access to:

```
az ad user show --id 0cbb4fd6-7091-44fb-ab5e-d2bd9c366f59
```

This cannot find the user because I'm logged into my organization regular AAD tenant. B2C tenants do not have subscriptions, they're linked to the primary tenant which means I can't do

```
az login -t myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

Working in the portal isn't handy, I'd like to do my routines in CLI. How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an option on the AZ CLI to access tenants without subscriptions.
Change your command to:

```
az login -t myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com --allow-no-subscriptions
```

Explanation from `az login -h`:

> Support access tenants without subscriptions. It's uncommon but useful to run tenant level commands, such as 'az ad'.

Comment: It seems that the behaviour has changed recently. Even though I use --allow-no-subscriptions I get an error. Is that also your experience?

Comment: I just needed to access B2C with CLI as well and for me, the parameter did the trick. I'm able to connect so it seems to still work.